# How to change font without changing document font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Surely this is easy, but I'm just beginning.

I've created a font and I want to change "My Words Here" without modifying the document font for the rest of the page.  I'm sure I just have the syntax wrong.  How do I fix it?

```
\newfontface\Gentium{Gentium}

\begin{Gentium}
\begin{center}
\begin{huge}
\textsc{My Words Here}
\end{huge}
\end{center}
\end{Gentium}
```

Comment: Why did you use those tags? If `gregorio` is involved, your example should mention it; the first line means nothing.

Comment: Sorry - I just realized those tokens and then I saw your comment.  I use a script to replace them. I'll remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just confine the font change in the environment. Note that Gentium doesn't provide small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\Gentium[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium}

\begin{document}
This is in the normal font
\begin{center}
\Gentium\huge
This is in the Gentium font
\end{center}
and back in the normal font.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A (probably) general LaTeX solution:

```
\newcommand{\BGMfont}{%
  \fontencoding{EncodingOfYourFont}% 
  \fontfamily{NameOfYourFont}%
  \fontsize{22}{25}% % about \huge
  \selectfont}
{\BGMfont My Words Here}
```

Without an illustration of the result, of course, because it is an answer for the first version of your question, when the name of the font was not known.